# Protractor - get result of sendChromiumCommand

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

**The goal**: obtain a result of chromium command execution, e.g. [Profiler](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Profiler/) report data

**What I've done**: I'm able to call chrome devtools command using `browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand`.

E.g. `await browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Page.reload', {})` reloads page, so I can confirm that this is working.

**The problem**: the result of any command execution is always `null`

Here is my code

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('whatever', async function() {
    await browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    const data = await browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Page.reload', {
      scriptToEvaluateOnLoad: `(function(){return '123 })()`
    });
    console.log(data); // expected '123' but got 'null'
  });
});
```

**Note**: the issue isn't connected to a particular command, all of the [devtools commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) return `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Protractor issue per se.

The problem is that underlying `selenium-webdriver` for Node.js uses `send_command`(which does not return result), but does not implement usage of `send_command_and_get_result`.

[According to response from developers](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8764) it's going to be fixed in next alpha release (current one is `4.0.0-alpha.7`)

I suppose that, in order for this to work, Protractor's `sendChromiumCommand` is gotta get a `sendChromiumCommandAndGetResult` counterpart, once `selenium-webdriver` fix is available.